# Class does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, oop

This is my protocol:

```
protocol LiveTableViewCellProtocol: class {
    var data: LiveCellObjectProtocol! { get set }
}
```

This is my class:

```
class RepliesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, LiveTableViewCellProtocol {
        var data: RepliesCellObject! //ERROR! does not conform to protocol.
}
```

`RepliesCellObject` is defined as:

```
public class RepliesCellObject: NSObject , LiveCellObjectProtocol{
    //basic stuff here.
}
```

`RepliesCellObject` is a LiveCellObjectProtocol ... so why doesn't my table cell conform?

Comment: In my RepliesTableViewCell, I must define my ```data``` as ```RepliesCellObject```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't conform because in an object that conforms to LiveTableViewCellProtocol, you can set data to *any* LiveCellObjectProtocol, including one that isn't an NSObject. In RepliesTableViewCell, you can't do that. The data must be set to a LiveCellObjectProtocol that is also an NSObject.

Therefore RepliesTableViewCell doesn't conform to LiveTableViewCellProtocol.

Comment: What about associatedtype?

Answer (score 0):

It must specifically be the same as the protocol says. What you're doing is not allowed because it is not the exact same. Remember, you can use `as!` to make it a RepleisCellObject if you're sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

`associatedtype` can help here

```
protocol LiveTableViewCellProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Data: LiveCellObjectProtocol
    var data: Data! { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use associated type

```
   protocol LiveTableViewCellProtocol: class {
        associatedtype Object : LiveCellObjectProtocol

        var data: Object! { get set }
    }
```